# The type MySiteName.SiteMap exists in both x.dll and y.dll?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, sitemap

The exact problem is that when i wish to utilize the SiteMap as in below i am getting error

```
imgBtnPrevious.PostBackUrl = SiteMap.CurrentNode != null ? (SiteMap.CurrentNode.PreviousSibling != null ? SiteMap.CurrentNode.PreviousSibling.Url : "") : "";

imgBtnNext.PostBackUrl = SiteMap.CurrentNode != null ? (SiteMap.CurrentNode.NextSibling != null ? SiteMap.CurrentNode.NextSibling.Url : "") : "";



Error ---> The type 'MySiteName.SiteMap' exists in both 'App_Web_3jyv5kio.dll' and 'App_Web_unds4iwr.dll'
```

How to solve this permanently, it shouldn't occur again. Deleting the temporary files is a manual solution and which will solve it only once i think, it will occur again ?

**UPDATE:**

i think it had something to do with asp.net server instance, i stopped it and then re started it, but now different error --> 'MySiteName.SiteMap' does not contain a definition for 'CurrentNode'

Answer (score 0):

Something must have gone wrong on your machine, because those temporary assemblies are cleaned up automatically (under normal circumstances).

Therefore, I'd say that you'll be ok once you kill those files.

If the problem comes back, you'll need to track what happens. (Quick note: If you host your application in IIS, then it's quite possible that something went wrong there, and code got recompiled even though the process was not recycled, which should NEVER happen under normal circumstances).

Comment: same issue on server as well !

Comment: Is it a Web Application Project, and are you putting your code in the App_Code directory?

Comment: its a website but a sitemap handler file is there in App_Code

Comment: Take it out of the App_Code folder.

Comment: i think it had something to do with asp.net server instance, i stopped it and then re started it, but now different error --> 'MySiteName.SiteMap' does not contain a definition for 'CurrentNode'

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the updated issue regarding `'MySiteName.SiteMap' does not contain a definition for 'CurrentNode'`

The problem was that the website had a page named SiteMap.aspx and hence its corresponding class was being picked up here. So to avoid this conflict we have to explicitly define the namespace of the class to pick simply as below

```
System.Web.SiteMap.CurrentNode
```

Now this will refer to the SiteMap of the site